# A few problems with installing Spore (Mac)

Tags: macos, spore

I'm trying to install Spore on my Mac (MacBook Pro 13', Dual Core, Snow-Leopard).

I'm having a few problems... Not long ago a friend of mine gave me his Spore copy and his Spore key code to try and install the game. As it commanded me to type in the code, it appeared to be invalid so I went ahead and just bought my own copy of Spore. I deleted the old game on my mac and installed the new one. It installed fine, but when I tried to play it, I had to wait about 20 minutes for it to tell me that the code is invalid. It didn't even let me try to type in my new code! What it sad was: Try reinstalling, purchasing a new copy and a new code and then trying again (What I actually did). It's still telling me to buy a new one...

The game also asked for updates. I updated it as many times as it wanted in hope to be able to play soon... With the newest update, it doesn't even let me open the game! It just crashes straight up!

I'm really close to throwing that game out of my window...  Would downloading a cracked version be illegal now?

Comment: Downloading a cracked version would be illegal. Whether it would be immoral is a different question.

Comment: Macs will store program-specific files in `/Library/Application Support/[program name]/` and `[home folder]/Library/Application Support/[program name]/`. These aren't usually removed when the program itself is Trashed. Uninstall again and check that there aren't files left over by Spore in those two places, which might include the old invalid key. (I'm not making this an answer because it's only an educated guess about what might be happening.)

Comment: When I tried installing Spore on my Mac, it would download and install an update every time I started it. This continued about 30 times over the course of an afternoon before I finally uninstalled it and just kept it on my PC. So much for getting it on launch day...

Comment: Pyro, the exact same thing happend to me -_-

Comment: @SevenSideDie There's nothing of spore i can remove in those folders...

Comment: @DailyDoggy: Mine didn't crash.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the EA Support forums themselves?

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you're trying to install Spore... http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/03/spore-sucks/

Comment: Download the crack. You paid for it, which is probably more than EA deserve when the DRM is preventing you from using the game.

Comment: Guys, is there a way for me to contact EA or the spore team and inform them of that?

Comment: Guaranteed this is related to their faulty DRM crud they shipped with the game ... you can contact EA but I really doubt they will resolve your issue. Hopefully you can get a refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your efforts!

I searched around other websites and found a soltion 2 my problem!

It appears that after being uninstalled, Spore lives a "Preferences"-folder behind which can't be spotted by App uninstall apps such as "AppDelete" which i used to uninstall Spore. After deleting that folder, the game gave me a chance to try my luck again and insert my Key-code, which i happily did!

The game was fun for the first 2 hours, but then got EXTREMLY repedetive. On stackexchange's gaming blog, there's a review of spore which tells that Spore is bad really BAD. I agree with it completly.

I think i already regret bying it...

The Review (as posted by Bwarner in a commet above): [Spore sucks.](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/03/spore-sucks/)

Thank you again for the support!

I <3 stackexchange

**THE PREFERENCE FOLDER IS UNDER:** /Users//Library/Preferences/Spore Preferences (originally posted by gavriels on the [macrumors forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=659903))

Comment: Can you tell us where this Preferences folder is located, for others who run into the same problem?